# how to save binary file to database

Tags: database, vb.net

Join Date: Dec 10
Posts: 10
caba11 is an unknown quantity at this point (<10)

how to save binary file to database
hi.
i need to save files into database...
i cant find why it is not working...

this is my code:

```
Public Sub importfiles(ByVal sFileName As String)

    Dim cnSQL As SqlConnection
    Dim cmSQL As SqlCommand
    Dim strSQL

    'Validate form values

    'Read file into a stream
    Dim fs As New FileStream(sFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
    Dim myData(fs.Length) As Byte
    fs.Read(myData, 0, fs.Length)
    fs.Close()

    Try

        'Build  SQL
        strSQL = "insert into data_cesta(ID, cesta) values (@ID, @cesta)"

        cnSQL = New SqlConnection("Data Source=.;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True")
        cmSQL = New SqlCommand(strSQL, cnSQL)

    cmSQL.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ID", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = ID
    cmSQL.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@cesta", SqlDbType.NText)).Value = myData
    '  cmd2.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ID
    ' cmd2.Parameters.Add("@cesta", SqlDbType.NText).Value = myData


    'Open connection and execute the command
    cnSQL.Open()
    cmSQL.ExecuteNonQuery()

    'Close and clean up objects
    cnSQL.Close()
    cmSQL.Dispose()
    cnSQL.Dispose()

    Catch ex As SqlException
    MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "SQL Error")
    Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "General Error")
    End Try

End Sub
```

without try it says "cmSQL.ExecuteNonQuery()"-"Failed to convert parameter value from a DataGridViewTextBoxColumn to a Int32."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as though you are loading some file paths into a DataGrid before having them processed into your database.

By default, your ID field is being passed to the procedure as the DataGridViewTextBoxColumn object within the DataGrid. You need to retrieve the text within that object.

You can do so by accessing the associated DataGridViewTextBoxCell object on the row being processed. Within the DataGridViewTextBoxCell object is a property called "Value" which will have the ID value you need.

Without seeing more code, it's hard to give you the exact code, but check out the [DataGridViewCell object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.value.aspx) for some helpful code, since the TextBoxCell inherits from this class.

Comment: i was trying this but still same error.... http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Save-and-Retrieve-Files-from-SQL-Server-Database-using-ASP.Net.aspx

Comment: Right now I don't think your problem is with the binary data reading, I think it is with getting the setting the ID value for your SqlCommand parameters, given the error that it can't convert the DataGridViewTextBoxColumn to an Integer.

Comment: you may also watch this video for explanation on how to add BLOB in ms access database with VBA:  https://youtu.be/JQz_8dkLyJ8